# Удаляется библиотека в Android Studio, хотя я уже добавил ее в Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

Пробовал добавлять 2 способами:
1. Закинул в папку сразу в AS и нажал Add new Library. 
2. Закинул в папку Libs и добавил в Graddle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
}
```

Тоже не помогло, есть другие способы?

Comment: что значит удаляется?

Comment: В прямом, прописываю import com..., а дальше автоматически удаляется

Answer (score 1):

Удаляется не библиотека, а неиспользуемый импорт (настройки студии). Создайте сначала объект, который хотите использовать, затем в подсказках выбирайте из предложенного списка нужную библиотеку для импорта.